# Is there a way to call a function via a selector from within a contract?

Tags: contract-invocation, evm, opcode, function-selector, encodefunctioncall

In the case of calling a function with signature `foo(uint256)` from contract `A`, I could use this construction in solidity:

```
address(A).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("foo(uint256)", 100));
// or alternatively with:
bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256("foo(uint256)"));
address(A).call(abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, 100));
```

However, I would like to make a call from within `A` to a given selector. Is there a way to do that (other than `address(this).call(...)`, which also only works if `foo` is external)? I know that the EVM has opcodes for JUMP and IJUMP to navigate within the bytecode of a contract, but can one pass a selector to such an opcode and is there a solidity way of doing it?